# gnuplot redirect data to a here-doc

Tags: gnuplot

This command works properly to write the results to the file "oneMonthDataOnlyfile.txt"

```
system("/usr/bin/sed -e '1,3d' " . "oneMonthData.txt" ." > oneMonthDataOnly.txt" );
```

Can I do the redirect to a here-doc, e.g.:

```
system("/usr/bin/sed -e '1,3d' " . "oneMonthData.txt" . ">  $myData);
```

When I try with the above formatting I get "parenthesis expected"

or with`system("/usr/bin/sed -e '1,3d' " . "oneMonthData.txt" ." > $myData " );`
sh: $myData: ambiguous redirect
ambiguous redirect

or: `system("/usr/bin/sed -e '1,3d' " . "oneMonthData.txt" >  $myData);`
 throws: "Column number or datablock line expected

Am I getting the formatting wrong or can a here-doc not be populated this way?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
set print $myData
print system("whatever command you like")
unset print
```

Comment: If the command used in `system()` results in many lines, gnuplot truncate it with message: `warning: *very* long system call output has been truncated`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible work out is to use a table:

```
set table $myData
plot "< /usr/bin/sed -e '1,3d' " . "oneMonthData.txt" u 1:2
unset table
```

Although note that this does not saves exactly the output, but only certain columns of it. In gnuplot documentation (i.e. `help table`) it says:

> When `table` mode is enabled, `plot` and `splot` commands print out a
>   multicolumn text table of values
>
> X Y {Z} `<flag>`
>
> rather than creating an actual plot on the current terminal.

Thus the shell output will actually follow that format.

**EDIT**

You can follow Ethan commentary and use `with table` style to plot more columns and without flags.

Comment: The separate plot mode "with table" exists to get around this limitation.  It dumps up to 14 columns of output with no extraneous flags.